# rxjs 6 error with ng test command while rxjs5 is registered in dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, karma-jasmine

When running `ng test` on my angular project, I run with errors that are related to  rxjs5 methods used with version 6.

```
error TS2339: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Subject
```

What is strange is that in my package.json the rxjs dependency is set to

```
"rxjs": "5.5.11"
```

The only dependency that requires rxjs 6 is ng-packagr, when I run `npm ls rxjs`, I get this output :

```
`-- ng-packagr@3.0.6
  `-- rxjs@6.3.2
```

No trace of my root dependency ?

If I run `npm ls` to get full details, I get

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.5.11
```

for my root dependency

And

```
| +-- rxjs@6.3.2
```

for ng-packagr dependency

When checking in the rxjs root folder of my node modules, the version appears to be 5.5.11.

Any idea of what's going on ?